# How to add macros to Word 2016?

Tags: javascript, macos, ms-word, ms-office, office-js

Is it possible to add macros to Word 2016 for Mac using the Word JavaScript API. I want to add macros and then call them from inside JavaScript code in my add-in. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only edit code within macro projects using the VBA Extensibility library, which is COM based and cannot be referenced by web add-ins.